# UWP app - how to save list of responses into file and getting data back

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, uwp

I am uploading files on `Amazon s3`  by parts. When uploading parts I am saving these into list, but I need to save this list into file and later get content back in original type and structure.

I am initializing list with:

```
List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();
```

And adding data in list:

```
uploadResponses.Add(await s3Client.UploadPartAsync(uploadRequest));
```

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: Suggestion only:  Serialize UploadPartResponse (XML perhaps?) save to file.

Comment: @Epistaxis It was first I have tried. But I can not back the same format :-( 
I have tried this jsonconvert
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uploadResponses)`

Comment: Well, we don't see what you have tried.... Sorry, given the requirements as they are currently written, the previous suggestion is what I have :)

Comment: @Epistaxis nop, even so thank you ....

Comment: Using JSON for storing the state should be enough. Could you post the UploadPartResponse code? How do the data you get back differ?